# Position absolute / relative change with css transform

Tags: html, css, transform

I try to create a list of element. When the mouse goes over one of the column, a transformation is applied (scale) to the column elements. A background appears to enforce this effect.

I use div's with floats, the background is created using a `:before` pseudo-element on header items. The `:before` pseudo-element has a `position:absolute` and is attached to the main container.

Everything works fine until I apply a `transform: scale(1.25)` to the header item. As soon as this property is applied, the `:before` pseudo-element is attached to the header instead of the container.

This fiddle show an exemple of the bug : http://jsfiddle.net/Elendev/z3ho4xre/

As soon as you pass the mouse on one of the table's element, the background becomes attached to the wrong element.

I tried to force the `position` property to `static` but it's not working.

**Here is the demo HTML code :**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="title"></div>
        <div class="col1">Col 1 header</div>
        <div class="col2">Col 2 header</div>
    </div>
    <div class="category">
        <h4>My category</h4>
        <div class="element col1">
            element 1
        </div>
        <div class="element col2">
            element 2
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="category">
        <h4>My second category</h4>
        <div class="element col1">
            element 1
        </div>
        <div class="element col2">
            element 2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
.container {
    position: relative;
}

h4, .header .title {
    width: 150px;
    height: 30px;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    margin: 0;
}

.col1, .col2 {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
}

.col1-hover .col1, .col2-hover .col2 {
    transform: scale(1.25);
}

.header .col1:before, .header .col2:before {
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100px;
    opacity: 0.4;
    background-color: red;
    transition: background-color 0.5s, transform 0.5s;
}

.header .col1:before {
    left: 150px;
}

.header .col2:before {
    left: 250px;
}

.col1-hover .header .col1:before, .col2-hover .header .col2:before {
    transform: scale(1.25);
    background-color: blue;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.category:after {
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}

.category .col1, .category .col2 {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

**The JavaScript to make it work :**

```
$(function() {
    $('.element').hover(function(event){
        var $element = $(event.target),
            containerClass;

        if($element.hasClass('col1')) {
            containerClass = 'col1-hover';
        } else {
            containerClass = 'col2-hover';
        }

        $('.container').addClass(containerClass);
    }, function(event){
        $('.container').removeClass('col1-hover col2-hover');
    });

});
```

Comment: your fiddle link doesnt even work.

Comment: It is not Fiddle link, it is Fiddle dont work))

Comment: make sure ur fiddle works.

Comment: Are you limited to your markup or can you swap the html around a bit? If it was a little more organized, you could attack it without the JS. If it needs to be responsive, this can be chiseled down - http://codepen.io/evanrbriggs/pen/tclJz

Comment: I see what you were doing by having the hover grouped by class rather than markup - if that's what you're working with let me know and I'll try and alternative.

Comment: @Evan I can change the markup. In the full table, there one level more, around `category`, and when the mouse goes over a column, it's higlighted on every `category` of every 'meta-category'. Plus when the mouse goes over a category, the column and the category have to be higlighted, I don't think I can avoid JS :-/